# creating timeline using vis examples

Tags: timeline

i am trying to create a timeline using vis examples..so far i have managed to put the code as below..however if i really see the example on web, it shows me the item bars. when i try to run this example on my computer, the items are missing on the timeline. what am i doing wrong here?console shows me no errors.

```
code->> <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Timeline | Individual editable items</title>

  <style>
    body, html {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 11pt;
    }

    div.vis-editable,
    div.vis-editable.vis-selected {
      /* custom styling for editable items... */
    }

    div.vis-readonly,
    div.vis-readonly.vis-selected {
      /* custom styling for readonly items... */
      background-color: #ff4500;
      border-color: red;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>


  <script src="dist/vis.js" rel="script"></script>
  <script src="dist/vis.min.js" rel="script"></script>
<link href="dist/vis.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <link href="dist/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <link href="dist/vis-timeline-graph2d.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>

<p>Specify individual items to be editable or readonly.</p>

<div id="visualization"></div>

<script>
  // create groups to highlight groupUpdate
var items = new vis.DataSet({
  type: { start: "ISODate", end: "ISODate" },
});

  // create a DataSet with items
  var items = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 1, content: 'Editable', editable: true, start: '2010-08-23', group: 1},
    {id: 2, content: 'Editable', editable: true, start: '2010-08-23T23:00:00', group: 2},
    {id: 3, content: 'Read-only', editable: false, start: '2010-08-24T16:00:00', group: 1},
    {id: 4, content: 'Read-only', editable: false, start: '2010-08-26', end: '2010-09-02', group: 2},
    {id: 5, content: 'Edit Time Only', editable: { updateTime: true, updateGroup: false, remove: false }, start: '2010-08-28', group: 1},
    {id: 6, content: 'Edit Group Only', editable: { updateTime: false, updateGroup: true, remove: false }, start: '2010-08-29', group: 2},
    {id: 7, content: 'Remove Only', editable: { updateTime: false, updateGroup: false, remove: true }, start: '2010-08-31', end: '2010-09-03', group: 1},
    {id: 8, content: 'Default', start: '2010-09-04T12:00:00', group: 2}
  ]);

  var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
  var options = {
    editable: true ,  // default for all items
     height: "300px",
  };

  var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items,options);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

example from web->> https://github.com/almende/vis/blob/master/examples/timeline/editing/individualEditableItems.html

i would appreciate any help here